# JSch directory traversion gives "End of file" error

Tags: ssh, sftp, jsch

I'm using JSch to traverse a remote directory and read all its contained files. I can retrieve the file names using the ChannelSftp.ls() method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003871/using-jsch-channelsftp-how-to-read-multiple-files-with-dynamic-names).

However, trying to read the files using ChannelSftp.get(), only the first three or four files work. After that, I get the following error message:

`1: End of file
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2198)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1294)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1266)
    at ...`

And for all subsequent files (after the first one failed with the above error), the error message is:

```
4: 
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2200)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1294)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1266)
```

I've tried different directories and different servers, so it's not about the particular file. Is that a systematic problem with JSch?

Comment: Currently, I am also facing the same error and on the same, the file is valid and as well as path is also vaid, Did you find any solution?